# Taxonomy planning - SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, taxonomy

Can any one share a link for short but very useful material on Taxonomy planning? It should not be from msdn but any other source.  short but very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I like this one - short and to the point: http://blog.cloudshare.com/2012/05/10/taxonomy-planning-in-sharepoint-2010/